# Removeing lines in a .eml files and copying the new "files" (destination A) into multiple files (destination B)

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I would like to create a batch file which finds certain keywords in .eml files (destination A) and then deletes the line in which they reside. After that I need the batch file to put the "new" files in separate .eml files in (destination B). the files can be .txt as well.

e.g 
line 2 needs to be removed which I can do using findstr, however my problem is that after I get the lines removed I can only place the "new file" in one .txt file and I need to place the "new files" in multiple .txt files in the same destination.

```
`e.g
DESTINATION A         "NEW FILE"           DESTINATION B
line1: good           line1: good          File1.txt 
line2: error     >    line2: good     >    File2.txt
line3: good                                File.... to however many "new files" i have.`
```

I have searched for a forcedir type command by I had no luck.

here is the code I use:

```
`findstr /v /I "2 3 7" C:\A\*.txt >> C:\B\onefileonly.txt
msg * Done!
exit >nul`
```

<----- this onefileonly.txt is my problem. I need it to be the seperate "new folders".

[Inside the onefileonly.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQbr.jpg)

---

I have also tried this code, however I has the same problem.

```
`@echo off
echo Removing...
for /f "skip=3 delims=*" %%a in (C:\A\testfile.txt) do (
echo %%a >>C:\B\onefileonly.txt
) >nul
echo Lines removed, rebuilding file...
xcopy C:\B\onefileonly.txt C:\A\testfile.txt /y >nul
echo File rebuilt, removing temporary files
del C:\B\onefileonly.txt /f /q >nul
msg * Done!
exit >nul`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after about a week i managed to bash together a script which answers this question, I still need to clean it up a bit but here is the code below

```
::CallScript
@echo off
CALL :ScriptA
CALL :ScriptB
CALL :ScriptC
pause
goto :eof

:ScriptA
del "C:\source\INCOMPLETE MESSAGE*.eml" "C:\source\EXCEPTION ERROR*.eml"
goto :eof

:ScriptB
@echo off
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (C:\source\*.eml) DO (
TYPE "%%i"| more /E +4 >> C:\5500\%%~ni.eml
)
goto :eof

:ScriptC
del "C:\source\ERROR WITH Position Post*.eml"
goto :eof
```

The script deletes the unwanted email files in source (which are INCOMPLETE MESSAGE & EXCEPTION ERROR )
Then the script takes the email files out of source, removes the top 4 lines in the .eml document copies them to the 5500 folder and lastly deletes the old .eml files in the source folder.